# How to create a square that redirects you in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have looked everywhere for an answer for this but to no avail, I want to create a button that is a square. When your mouse goes over **any** part of the square I need it to be clickable. I'm very new to CSS so an example would be nice, thank you.

Comment: Please define clickable. Should the style change on click, or does some other action need to happen? If the goal is to redirect the user to another page you will need to use HTML (`<a>` tag) or JavaScript (`window.location`) to do that

Comment: @MatthewHerbst by clickable i mean when you press on your mouse it can redirect you (<a>) to another page. I just cant get the button to be square, its just a rectangle

Answer (score 0):

You can style the button like this.

```
.btn {
    border: 2px outset green;
    background-color: lightGreen;
    height:75px;
    width:75px;
    cursor:pointer;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 4px 2px;
}

.btn:hover {
   background-color: green;
   color:white;
}
```

And apply this style class to the button.

```
<button class= "btn" onclick="myFunction()"> Click Here </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can make button with tag `<a> ... </a>`, for example:

```
<a class="btn" href="www.facebook.com">Facebook</a>
```

and make the style:

```
.btn {border: 1px solid black; padding: 10px; text-decoration: none;}
```